# What is stylelint's default properties order within a block?

Tags: css, properties, stylelint

I know the answer should be simple to find, however the only reference to "order" I found in the [stylelint's official website](https://stylelint.io) was the [stylelint-order plugin](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order), which seems interesting enough but it's a bit too overkill for my needs (not planning to install and configure it for now).

Stylelint suggests (by sending warnings) a specific order of properties within a block, i.e. this block:

```
.my-class {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #dadada;
}
```

Would send warnings with `property-sort-order` in all the inner lines. So what is the required order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply **alphabetic** (A-Z). Therefore, for avoiding the stylelint warnings, the properties in that block should be ordered like this:

```
.my-class {
  background: #dadada;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

However with [SASS interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____), it is possible to do disregard this order enforcement like this:

```
$bg: background;

.my-class {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  #{bg}: #dadada;
}
```

Comment: is alphabetic a default one? stylelint doesn't warn about, say, `align-items` at the end of a block even thought it has to be in the beginning if it were alphabetic